# cfif inside loop through columns for table headings not working

Tags: loops, coldfusion

I'm new here so forgive me for all the formatting errors.  I'm trying all the help topics...

Using coldfusion, I'm trying to display all columns in a table heading except for 2 of them.  They all show up.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
<cfloop list="#ArrayToList(getTableDataHeading.getColumnNames())#"index="col" >
    <cfif "#col#" NEQ "itemID" or "#col#" NEQ "locationID">
        <th>#col#</th>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: The pound signs inside the cfif tag are unnecessary but are probably not causing the problem.  To troubleshoot, display the array first.  Then, inside your loop, first display #col# and then do your if statement.  Add an else clause that outputs information such as 'inside else clause', what you expected, and what you got.

Comment: Not related to your question, but there is no need to for the ArrayToList function.  Unless you are on a very old version of CF, you can loop through the array.

Comment: I second @DanBracuk tips about debugging. Getting a handle on basic troubleshooting techniques is as important as learning the language basics, IMO and something that will help you solve all kinds of problems in the future. Here is a rough example, using Dan's suggestions http://trycf.com/gist/09a3236ae03d8838821a/acf2016?theme=monokai . Note, there are simpler options but I left in the original code to better illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using wrong condition in your cfif statement.
You need **AND** condition and not the **OR** condition. [Learn how operators work here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09d55-7ffc.html).

```
<cfoutput>
    <cfloop list="#ArrayToList(getTableDataHeading.getColumnNames())#"index="col" >
       <cfif col NEQ "itemID" AND col NEQ "locationID">
          <th>#col#</th>
       </cfif>
   </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

You should also try to avoid unnecessary use of # sign. Check out the difference between your cfif statement and mine regarding the use of # sign.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @malibu65k Happy to help.

Comment: @Malibu65k - Agreed. The OR operator is definitely the issue.  If yoiu are new to CF, using list functions is a simpler option for handling any number of values without requiring a separate comparison for each one: http://trycf.com/gist/fd0809564923e16e292e/acf2016?theme=monokai

Comment: Actually Leigh, I'm not new to programming itself at all, CF, a few years now, but you'd think I was a newbie,  I looked at that several hours off and on and still didn't see it.  I'm embarrassed!  LOL!!  "list"  sounds like a good option being I added another criteria.  Thanks for the suggestion.